# SQL server management studio 2014 setting only returns whole numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, settings, appsettings, query-analyzer

Does anyone know if there is a setting within the app itself that would cause it to only return whole numbers?

Example - query is set up to return data 123456789.26 but is being rounded to a whole number 123456789

I cannot find any settings or options in the program.  I was able to get the same results by using the STR command, but I shouldn't have to.  My colleagues use other versions of SQL server and some return the decimals while others don't.

Comment: `query is set up to return data 123456789.26`, what does it mean?, what query?. `but is being rounded to a whole number 123456789`, when is it being rounded?. Please post more details

Comment: Please provide the datatype of the column you are querying and the query. I'm not aware of any setting like that

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no global setting that tells SQL Server to round all numeric values.

There is only one setting that can cause anything like this. However it would happen through truncation rather than a system setting that forces rounding.

Under Tools > Options > Query Results > Results to Text, there is a property called "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column".

Based on your description, I have a feeling this is not the case. Mostly because the default value is 256.